# Set DataTimeField model field value to timezone.now + timezone.timedelta(hours=another_model_field)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add an end date to an advertisement:

```
class AdvertisePost(Post):
    ...
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=48)
    finish = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now + timezone.timedelta(hours=duration))
```

The `duration` is the number of hours the advertisement is supposed to run. So I want `finish` to equal the creation time of `AdvertisePost` + `duration`. I have attempted to do this with:

```
finish = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now + timezone.timedelta(hours=duration))
```

I was told `default=timezone.now` is to be used instead of `default=timezone.now()` as the latter will return the current time and not the time of creation.

As for the other part of the field, `hours=duration` is returning the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta hours component: IntegerField
```

Any idea how I can go about getting `finish` to be a date object that equals the creation time of `AdvertisePost` + duration?

**Edit**

Model function:

```
@property
def done(self):
    return timezone.now + timezone.timedelta(hours=self.duration)
```

How come this won't work?^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It successfully works in my views when the `AdvertisePost` form is submitted:

```
ad.finish = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(hours=ad.duration)
```

Don't see any need to formulate the `finish` value in my models.

Answer (score 0):

try to override **`save()`** method of your model as

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta


class AdvertisePost(models.Model):
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=48)
    finish = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:  # newly created object
            self.finish = timezone.now() + timedelta(hours=self.duration)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**UPDATE-1**
You could also do this with `property` decorator as,

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta


class AdvertisePost(models.Model):
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=48)

    @property
    def finish(self):
        return timezone.now() + timedelta(hours=self.duration)
```

Comment: I will try this, but how come a regular model function won't work? `def finish(self):
        return timezone.now + timezone.timedelta(hours=self.duration)` ?

Comment: sorry.. I don't understand :(

Comment: you mean property?

Comment: Yes. I've added in my edit what I mean. Also, I'm still getting the `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta hours component: IntegerField` on your `save()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`AdvertisePost.duration` is a `models.IntegerField` object, and although Django implements all methods necessary to make it behave like a real integer, it still can't be used where the `int` or `float` type is specifically checked for, as is the case here with the `hours` parameter for `timedelta`.

In this case you just have to explicitly cast it `int`:

```
finish = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now + timezone.timedelta(hours=int(duration)))
```

Comment: Returns this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'IntegerField'`